# How to create a new window with button click

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I want to create a new window when a button is clicked. I will later have windows be created dynamically depending on inputted data. But I want to start simple first.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QPushButton, QGridLayout, QWidget

class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, QPushButton):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__()
        centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)
        self.setWindowTitle("ASSET")
        self.Button = QPushButton('Action',self)
        self.Button.clicked.connect(self.Action)
        self.layout = QGridLayout(centralWidget)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.Button)


    def Action(self):
        pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create another `QMainWindow()` and when the button is clicked, activate the `show()` method

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QPushButton, QGridLayout, QWidget, QLabel

class NewWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(NewWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.label = QLabel('New Window!')
        centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)
        self.layout = QGridLayout(centralWidget)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label)

class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, QPushButton):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__()
        centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)
        self.setWindowTitle("ASSET")
        self.Button = QPushButton('Action',self)
        self.Button.clicked.connect(self.Action)
        self.layout = QGridLayout(centralWidget)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.Button)

        self.new_window = NewWindow(self)

    def Action(self):
        self.new_window.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]